# Cast from filtered custom List<T> with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, lambda

I have a custom list which inherits from `Generic.List<T>` like this:

```
public class TransferFileList<T> : List<TransferFile> { .. }
```

When I set (where '`Files`' is a `TransferFileList<T>`):

```
var files = uploadResponse.Files.Where(x => !x.Success).ToList()
```

the '`files`' object resolves as `System.Collections.Generic.List<TransferFile>`, not `TransferFileList<T>`, which is what I would expect as it was what was being filtered through the `Where`, so how could I successfully return a list of `TransferFileList<T>` into 'files'?

I did try:

```
var files = uploadResponse.Files.Where(x => !x.Success).ToList() 
as TransferFileList<TransferFile>;
```

but using that safe cast, it just resolves as null.

Thanks guys and gals.

Comment: What do you get if "var files = uploadResponse.Files.Where(x => !x.Success)" ?

Comment: @Kirk OP will get an `IEnumerable<TransferFile>`

Comment: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[TransferFile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I have to ask why you are inheriting from `List<T>`? 99% of the time that's a bad idea.

If you want to extend the functionality of a list, use extension methods:

```
public static something PrintErrors(this List<TransferFile> list)
{
    //do your printing logic
}
```

On to the answer: `ToList()` operates on an `IEnumerable<T>` and converts the members of the sequence to a `List` of the same type. Since you inherit from `List<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, that's what happens there.

`Where()` works the same way - operates on an `IEnumerable<T>` and returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

To get some arbitrary list-like object back, like you have, you need to add the items in a sequence to your custom list, like so:

```
var myFiles = new TransferFileList<TransferFile>();
myFiles.AddRange(originalFileList.Where(condition));
```

Comment: Why is it bad Rex? Hopefully I'm 1% :) I have a PrintErrors() method which returns any of my response's attached errors as a print-friendly string.

Comment: @GONeale because nothing works like you expect it to when you inherit from List, just like this situation. See my revised answer for an alternative.

Comment: Very good point there Rex on the x-method, however can they touch instance variables? I don't think so as they exist outside of the instance, I have a line like this in printErrors:
<pre>string internalErrorMessage = StoreErrorBase.GetMessage(file.Error);</pre> (file.Error) being an 'Error' property on the instance of 'TransferFile'.

Comment: @GONeale an extension method on a list has access to all the public members of the underlying list and all the items in the list.

Comment: Thanks Rex, reluctantly I guess I have to introduce a new variable and new list assignment like you state.  No problem though if it's the preferred method!

Comment: @Rex oh yes, of course, silly me, obviously being in 'list' specified above with the 'this' attribute.

Comment: @Rex Well! Maybe moving to an extension method might be best now! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extension method for `IEnumerable<TransferFile`> to handle that scenario:

```
public static TransferFileList ToTransferFileList(
    this IEnumerable<TransferFile> files)
{
    return new TransferFileList(files);
}

// ...

var files = uploadResponse.Files.Where(x => !x.Success).ToTransferFileList();
```

This provides you with the `TransferFileList` instead of just a `List<TransferFile>`. Note the reason your `as` returns `null` is because while `TransferFileList` is a `List<TransferFile>`, the same does not hold in the other direction. That is, your `List<TransferFile>` is NOT a `TransferFileList` object.

I agree with @RexM that any attempt at subclassing `List<T>` be avoided due to the multitude of pitfalls associated. I suggest Composition (Has-A rather than Is-A) or sticking with the base class library collections instead.

Comment: We don't know if TransferFileList has no ctor that takes a sequence, and even if it did, it's treating the symptom not the cause of the problem.

Comment: He may genuinely need additional functionality found in `TransferFileList`. I agree though that composition would serve him better than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

I like SLV's extension approach, but is there any other straight casting approach?

If not I might just go with the reverted in-line approach I was hoping to avoid:

```
var transferFiles = new TransferFileList<TransferFile>();
if (files != null) 
  transferFiles.AddRange(files);
```